# windows phone 7 - saving image state in isolated storage

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

Hello friends Am new to Windows phone am developing one app for learning

this is a single page app with group of images and am displaying images based on **Image_tap()** it working perfectly. now i want to save the image state ( source of the image) when **Application_closing** and i want to retrieve the state **Application_launching**

in **MainPage.xaml.cs** file

```
 PhoneApplicationService phoneAppservice = PhoneApplicationService.Current;     
 private void Image_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Image mybutton = (Image)sender;
        image1.Source = mybutton.Source;
        phoneAppservice.State["myValue"] = mybutton.Source;
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object value;
        if (phoneAppservice.State.TryGetValue("myValue", out value))
        {
            image1.Source = (System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)value;
        }
    }
```

in **app.xaml.cs** file:

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        getSource();
    }

 private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        saveSource();
    }

private void saveSource()
    {
        PhoneApplicationService phoneAppservice = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        settings["myValue"] = phoneAppservice.State["myValue"];
    }

    private void getSource()
    {
        PhoneApplicationService phoneAppservice = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        object myValue;
        if(settings.TryGetValue<object>("myValue", out myValue))
        {
            phoneAppservice.State["myValue"] = myValue;
        }
    }
```

am saving the getting image source and not able to set that source to my image. i think am missing something or please suggest anther correct way

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded`. is it the MainPage's Loaded event handler ? If so place a break point there and tell what value you are getting in the `value` field?

Comment: Thanks for your replay..! I'm just fallow the chanal9 video that works fine for textBox value. now i fixed this problem previously i am trying to save image source in state i think that is wrong

Comment: If your problem is solved, then post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice..! and you posted useful concepts in your blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In state i have saved the image name instead of image source and after that given a path to that image to display

in **MainPage.xaml.cs** file
i have used single Image_Tap event for multiple images

```
 private void Image_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Image mybutton = (Image)sender; // calcifying image based on image taped  
        image1.Source = mybutton.Source; // setting tapped source to image 
        phoneAppservice.State["myValue"] = mybutton.Name; // here saving the name of the image 
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object value;
        if (phoneAppservice.State.TryGetValue("myValue", out value))
        {
            //retrieving the image name form state and creating new BitMapimage based on this name 
            BitmapImage newImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Gallery;component/Images/"+value+".jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            image1.Source = newImg; 
        }
    }
```

in App.xaml.cs file

here saving the state in isolated storage when application_closing and retrieving the state form isolated storage when application launching

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        getSource();
    }

 private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        saveSource();
    }

 private void saveSource()
    {
        PhoneApplicationService phoneAppservice = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        settings["myValue"] = phoneAppservice.State["myValue"]; //storing the state (image name) to isolated storage

    }

    private void getSource()
    {
        PhoneApplicationService phoneAppservice = PhoneApplicationService.Current;
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        object myValue;
        if(settings.TryGetValue<object>("myValue", out myValue))
        {
            phoneAppservice.State["myValue"] = myValue; // saving the state from isolated storage
        }
    }
```